# How to make NetBeans automatically move you inside curly braces?

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded NetBeans as a replacement for Eclipse, and I like it so far, but there's one thing I can't figure out.
In eclipse, when you are inside two curly braces and press enter, it will move you inside the body and add a tab. It doesn't do it in NetBeans, and I would like to know if there's a setting/plugin that does that. Example (The pipe symbol "|" is the location of the cursor, AKA the thing that shows you where you are typing):

### Eclipse:

**Before pressing enter:**

```
public void example(){|}
```

**After pressing enter:**

```
public void example(){
    |
}
```

### NetBeans:

**Before pressing enter:**

```
public void example(){|}
```

**After pressing enter:**

```
public void example(){
|}
```

Answer (score 0):

try Editing Code Templates

1.Choose Tools > Options > Editor > Code Templates.

2.From the Language drop down list, select Java (or whichever language you want to create a code template for). The list of abbreviations and associated templates is displayed.

3.Use the New and Remove buttons to add or remove templates in the list. To edit an existing template, select the template and edit the code in the Expanded Text field below the list.

4.Choose the key which will be used to expand the templates. The default key is Tab.

To more about Code Assistance learn here:
   https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/editor-codereference.html